# Converting a pointer to different type in C

Tags: c, type-conversion, c99

```
int i = 42;
int *p1 = &i;
int long *p2 = (long*)p1;
```

Is this undefined behavior? In C++, I think it is implementation defined behavior for some reason.

I looked in C Standard:

> C99 6.3.2.3/7 A pointer to an object or incomplete type may be
>   converted to a pointer to a different object or incomplete type. If
>   the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned 57) for the pointed-to
>   type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again,
>   the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.
>
> 57) In general, the concept "correctly aligned" is transitive: if a
>   pointer to type A is correctly aligned for a pointer to type B, which
>   in turn is correctly aligned for a pointer to type C, then a pointer
>   to type A is correctly aligned for a pointer to type C.

What does the term correctly aligned mean here in practice? How do you know if you're doing it correctly without stepping into Undefined behavior?

Comment: It's Undefined Behavior if you dereference `p2`. Reason: You violate strict-aliasing.

Comment: `int long *p2`??? what is long here?

Comment: On 32bit arch, sizeof(int) == sizeof(long), so there is no difference. On 64 - you'll have some garbage on other half of long, or could even leave allocated memory regions, so again - there is no point to do that. Other than that, it's correct.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra: `int long *p2` is a legitimate but slightly unorthodox way of writing `signed long int *p2`, `long *p2`, `long int *p2` or `long int signed *p2` (these are all equivalent to each other).

Comment: In a 64-bit environment on RISC machines, there's a decent chance that `i` will be aligned on an odd 32-bit address boundary but `long` must be aligned on a 64-bit address boundary (or even 32-bit address boundary).  Therefore, on such systems, you would get a SIGBUS if you tried to read or modify memory via `p2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It basically means that if, say, `int` is aligned to 4 bytes, and `int long` is aligned to 8 bytes, the behavior is undefined. Say you have something like:

```
 0x04     0x08    0x0C    0x10
+------+-------+-------+-------+
|      |       |   i   |       |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

In this case, `&i == 0x0C` (which is valid because `int` is aligned to 4 bytes). When you cast to `int long*`, the pointer is converted to an aligned one: `p2 == 0x08`, because our theoretical system aligns `int long` to 8 bytes, so you'd be basically reading off an address you don't own if you dereference `p1`, ergo the undefined behavior.

Comment: So, basically if the sizeof two pointer types is not the same, say sizeof int and sizeof long is not equal then you get undefined behavior, right?

Comment: @user963241 AFAIK, alignment and size aren't always the same. I'd advise against doing this. Why do you need to anyway?

Comment: Just curious about what causes the undefined behavior when converting between pointer types. Thanks for advice.

Comment: `sizeof(int *) == sizeof(long *)` — the pointer sizes are the same.  But the alignment requirements are not necessarily the same.  On RISC chips (not Intel), an N-byte type (N = 1, 2, 4, 8) should be aligned on an N-byte boundary.  Intel doesn't enforce that (but there's a performance penalty if you use misaligned pointers).

Comment: Accessing the type-punned pointer leads to undefined behaviour.

Comment: Can I check the alignment requirements for types in gcc?